# Java - Method Code Coverage at Runtime

Tags: java, api, runtime, code-coverage

I would like to find out if it is possible to obtain code coverage at runtime within the Java environment.

Given a method that is invoked at runtime ( via the Reflection API ), is it possible to obtain the code coverage / other coverage measure after the method is executed.

This would allow me to test methods with different parameters and quickly evaluate the code coverage after each run. If so, what libraries / frameworks offer this functionality.

Comment: [JaCoCo](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/).

Comment: You mean, through the JVM itself?

Comment: Any technique as long as I can obtain the results immediately after the method has been executed via runtime invocations.

Answer (score 0):

you might have a look at JaCoCo. Its pretty simple to use and has with ECLEmma an easy to use eclipse plugin.

Cheers.